# An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType": The options "0", "1" do not exist

Tags: php, symfony

I just started learning symfony framework, and I got an error.

> An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType": The options "0", "1" do not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file_upload", "always_empty", "attr", "attr_translation_parameters", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "block_prefix", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "help", "help_attr", "help_html", "help_translation_parameters", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "is_empty_callback", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "label_html", "label_translation_parameters", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "row_attr", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".

I didn't even set 0 or 1 anywhere. The error occurs when trying to visit https://127.0.0.1:8000/register.
My code registration controller is

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="register")
     */
    public function register()
    {

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class,[
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => ['label','Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label','Confirm Password']
            ])
            ->getForm();
        return $this->render('registration/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

I've been following symfony tutorial on youtube and he doesn't get an error.
What can I do? Thanks

**Edit**
I had an error in 'first_options' and 'second_options'
The right way was
'first_options' => ['label' => 'Password'],
'second_options' => ['label' =>'Confirm Password']

Comment: Do you miss the resolver or did you not added it here to your question?

Comment: I haven't added it here, I found where mistake was ---- 'first_options' => ['label' => 'Password'], 'second_options' => ['label' =>'Confirm Password']

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('username', TextType::class)
        ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
            'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
            'required' => true,
            'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
            'second_options' => ['label' => 'Confirm Password'],
        ])
        ->getForm();
```

and in view :

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_row(form.username) }}
        {{ form_row(form.password.first) }}
        {{ form_row(form.password.second) }}
        <button type="submit">Register!</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the validation bundle is not installed, you will get this error. To fix it, you need to install the validation bundle by running the following command:

> composer req validation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).